# How to fix SQL syntax error using liquibase and mysql to create trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, maven, triggers, liquibase

I am setting up first liquibase maven project for a MySQL DB.  Been fine up to creating the triggers.

I believe it is an issue with liquibase and JDBC not correctly handling a multiple statement SQL, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Here are my pom dependancies

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.3</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my liquibase include file

```xml
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

  <changeSet id="event_horizon_1_0_0" author="lmtyler" dbms="mysql">
    <sql>
      drop trigger if exists ai_event_approval;
    </sql>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="event_horizon_1_0_1" author="lmtyler" dbms="mysql">
    <sqlFile splitStatements="false" stripComments="false" endDelimiter="DONE" path="01__ai_event_approval.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
  </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

This is my sql file

```sql
CREATE DEFINER ='evclient'@'%' TRIGGER ai_event_approval
    AFTER INSERT
    ON event_approval
    FOR EACH row
begin
    insert into event_approval_log (rowAction,
                                    actionTs,
                                    event,
                                    requestorEmail,
                                    requestReason,
                                    statusType,
                                    approverUserId,
                                    approverReason,
                                    lastChangTs)
        values ('I',
                current_timestamp(6),
                new.event,
                new.requestorEmail,
                new.requestReason,
                new.statusType,
                new.approverUserId,
                new.approverReason,
                new.lastChangTs);
end;
# DONE
```

I expected that by setting the splitStatements, stripComments, and endDelimiter that I would get liquibase to send the whole SQL as one thru JDBC.

But I am getting this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3:update (default) on project event-horizon-mysql: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set /Users/lmtyler/OneDrive - Walmart Inc/workspace/code/event-horizon/event-horizon-mysql/src/main/java/resources/liquibase/schema/triggers/02__au_event_approval.sql::event_horizon_1_0_1::lmtyler:
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 23 [Failed SQL: CREATE TRIGGER au_event_approval
[ERROR]     AFTER UPDATE
[ERROR]     ON event_approval
[ERROR]     FOR EACH row
[ERROR] begin
[ERROR]     insert into event_approval_log (rowAction,
[ERROR]                                     actionTs,
[ERROR]                                     event,
[ERROR]                                     requestorEmail,
[ERROR]                                     requestReason,
[ERROR]                                     statusType,
[ERROR]                                     approverUserId,
[ERROR]                                     approverReason,
[ERROR]                                     lastChangTs)
[ERROR]     values ('U',
[ERROR]             current_timestamp(6),
[ERROR]             new.event,
[ERROR]             new.requestorEmail,
[ERROR]             new.requestReason,
[ERROR]             new.statusType,
[ERROR]             new.approverUserId,
[ERROR]             new.approverReason,
[ERROR]             new.lastChangTs)]
```

Comment: Maybe it helps when you let liquibase run with `updateSQL` instead of `update`. Then liquibase will not run the changes directly on the db but print them to std. That way you could examine how your sql file gets parsed.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the suggestion! Changed to `updateSQL` checked the output file.  They produced the correct SQL results
`... new.lastChangTs);
   end;` but when I change back to `update` it yet again truncates the `; end;` from the SQL and got the same error as above.

Comment: Cool. Maybe then it's a problem on the JDBC side. You could try to use `allowMultiQueries=true` in your config for the JDBC connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nights sleep along with @Jens suggestion I finally see the issue.

First if you see my post the error was not for the SQL I thought.
I thought it was the `AFTER INSERT` that was throwing the error, but it was the `AFTER UPDATE`

The key was to make sure to set `splitStatements:false`, setting the `endDelimiter` was not needed.

Here are two examples that work:

```xml
<changeSet id="event_horizon_1_0_1" author="lmtyler" dbms="mysql">
    <sqlFile splitStatements="false" stripComments="false" path="01__ai_event_approval.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

with this sql file

```sql
CREATE DEFINER ='evclient'@'%' TRIGGER ai_event_approval
    AFTER INSERT
    ON event_approval
    FOR EACH row
begin
    insert into event_approval_log (rowAction,
                                    actionTs,
                                    event,
                                    requestorEmail,
                                    requestReason,
                                    statusType,
                                    approverUserId,
                                    approverReason,
                                    lastChangTs)
        values ('I',
                current_timestamp(6),
                new.event,
                new.requestorEmail,
                new.requestReason,
                new.statusType,
                new.approverUserId,
                new.approverReason,
                new.lastChangTs);
end;
```

And here is using the SQL format

```sql
--changeset lmtyler:event_horizon_1_0_1 dbms:mysql splitStatements:false
CREATE TRIGGER au_event_approval
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON event_approval
    FOR EACH row
begin
    insert into event_approval_log (rowAction,
                                    actionTs,
                                    event,
                                    requestorEmail,
                                    requestReason,
                                    statusType,
                                    approverUserId,
                                    approverReason,
                                    lastChangTs)
    values ('U',
            current_timestamp(6),
            new.event,
            new.requestorEmail,
            new.requestReason,
            new.statusType,
            new.approverUserId,
            new.approverReason,
            new.lastChangTs);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when executing a trigger inside **sql** tag. If you are executing a block of code in liquibase don't forget to add **splitStatements:false** to your **sql** tag.

```
<changeSet id="your_id" author="your_name">

    <comment>your comments</comment>

    <sql splitStatements="false">
        CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
        BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        --Your Code Block
        END;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```