# How to substitute property values in Liquibase?

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a *changelog-root.xml* file with the following properties:

```
<property  name="identity"  value="bigserial"  dbms="postgresql"/>
<property  name="identity"  value="identity"  dbms="h2"/>
...
<include file="changelog-create-schema.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

And in the *changelog-create-schema.sql* i would like to substitute them like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_token (
    id ${identity} primary key,
    token_encrypted varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    expiration timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

I have read the liquibase documentation and used the same syntax as described here:
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html

But its not working for me i get:

**liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"**

Can u help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

Per accepted solutions on the similar post linked below, you need to add

```
 <sql splitStatements="false">
```

or something along those lines. Take a look at the answers on the post and see if you're able to resolve it with that info.

Reference:

- [How to fix SQL syntax error using liquibase and mysql to create trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098328/how-to-fix-sql-syntax-error-using-liquibase-and-mysql-to-create-trigger)